# How to get appropriate timestamp in c for logs?

Tags: c, logging, timestamp

I'm creating a client-server application. I want to do some logging.

Server is in C. Now I'm print messages to the terminal. So I'll probably just copy that to sprintf and add timestamp. 
How can I do that timestamp?
It should probably include date, hours, minutes, seconds.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#include <time.h>
void timestamp()
{
    time_t ltime; /* calendar time */
    ltime=time(NULL); /* get current cal time */
    printf("%s",asctime( localtime(&ltime) ) );
}
```

On my PC, it just prints

```
Wed Mar 07 12:27:29 2012
```

Check out the whole range of time related functions here
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html

Comment: That's not appropriate. But you are most of there way there. You needed this to be 2012-03-07 12:27:29 as a minimum.  Logs get grepped. logs get sorted. Logs get ingested into ELK and Splunk.

Answer (score 11):

Please find the thread safe version of Pavan's answer below.

```
time_t ltime;
struct tm result;
char stime[32];

ltime = time(NULL);
localtime_r(&ltime, &result);
asctime_r(&result, stime);
```

Please refer to [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/ctime.3.html) for more details.