# Correcting timestamp on C code log file

Tags: c, logging, time, timestamp, raspberry-pi

I'm currently programming my Raspberry Pi (model B) with a DHT11 temperature & humidity sensor and lcd display. I have written a C script which logs values obtained from the temperature sensor to a status file which is then added to a log file. The script is as follows:

```
#include <time.h>

#define LOGFILE "/var/log/temp.log"
#define CURRENTFILE "/var/temp.data"



/* Saves the date time and humidity to a log file and current file */


void write_value (int temp, int humidity) {

    time_t current_time;
    current_time = time(NULL);

    /* Write to log file */
    FILE *logfd;
    logfd = fopen (LOGFILE, "a");
    fprintf (logfd, "%ld %d %d\n", current_time, temp, humidity);
    fclose (logfd);

    /* Write to current file */
    FILE *currfd;
    currfd = fopen(CURRENTFILE, "w");
    fprintf (currfd, "%ld %d %d\n", current_time, temp, humidity);
    fclose (currfd); 

}
```

It works, however; the output I get in the log file is as follows:

```
1428539174 16 41
1428539232 17 40
1428539257 18 40
1428539304 19 39
1428539319 19 39
```

With the first row intended to be the date & time stamp, the temperature, and the humidity.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I could fix the date & time, as well as changing it to a DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS (Day/Month/Year Hour:Min:Sec) format?

Based on suggestions from @pmg the script was changed to:

```
#include <time.h>

#define LOGFILE "/var/log/temp.log"
#define CURRENTFILE "/var/temp.data"



/* Saves the date time and humidity to a log file and current file */


void write_value (int temp, int humidity) {

    char dt[20]; // space enough for YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and terminator
    struct tm tm;
    time_t current_time;
    current_time = time(NULL);
    tm = *localtime(&current_time); // convert time_t to struct tm
    strftime(dt, sizeof dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm); // format

    /* Write to log file */
    FILE *logfd;
    logfd = fopen (LOGFILE, "a");
    fprintf (logfd, "%s %d %d/n", dt, temp, humidity);
    fclose (logfd);

    /* Write to current file */
    FILE *currfd;
    currfd = fopen(CURRENTFILE, "w");
    fprintf (currfd, "%s %d %d/n", dt, temp, humidity);
    fclose (currfd); 

}
```

Comment: convert the `time_t` value to `struct tm`, then use `strftime()` to format appropriately.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this. Would you be able to show me how to do that I'm the script I posted if it's not too much hassle? @pmg

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596945/how-to-get-appropriate-timestamp-in-c-for-logs?rq=1 (but I'm too lazy to confirm it).

Comment: I'll have a look thanks @mah

Comment: @mah: same basic issue, but the chosen/recommended solutions in the other question don't mention `strftime()` — any more than the solution here mentions `asctime()` — so they are complementary rather than duplicate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `time_t` value to `struct tm` and then format appropriately

```
char dt[20]; // space enough for DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS and terminator
struct tm tm;
time_t current_time;

current_time = time(NULL);
tm = *localtime(&current_time); // convert time_t to struct tm
strftime(dt, sizeof dt, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm); // format

fprintf(currfd, "%s %d %d\n", dt, temp, humidity);
```

See the POSIX descriptions of [`localtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) and [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html).

Comment: I've edited the question with the script I tried to enter based on your earlier answer (see bottom of the question). Could you confirm if this is correct or have I entered it wrong? @pmg

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a couple of `&`. Answer edited by adding one to the `localtime` line and another to the `strftime` line.

Comment: I really appricate your help.
I updated the C script accordingly, however; the output of the log file is the same:

`1428589484 19 38`
`1428589551 19 38`
`1428589628 21 38`
`1428589726 19 38`
`1428589842 21 38`

Any idea why this could be? @pmg

Comment: it works on [codepad](http://codepad.org/Ejnkm6pl) and [ideone](http://ideone.com/WaY6FX). I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: On codepad and ideone; do you happen to know how the output and stdout respectively convert the 10 figure number produced to the date & time (i.e. 1428590469 ==> 09/04/2015 14:41:09 and 1428595417 ==> 09/04/2015 16:03:37)? @pmg

Comment: ideone's clock if off by about one hour and a half. `1428595417 - 1428590469` is 4948 seconds or 82 minutes... and then there's the timezone issue to take into acccount.

Comment: FWIW: It is often easier to process data if the date format follows ISO 8601, more or less, using 2015-04-09 08:34:52 or thereabouts as a format.  All else apart, it means you can sort into time order with a simple lexicographic sort.  Granted, log files are written sequentially, but if you need to merge two log files to compare different sets of readings, this makes it easier.